# Can't get rotated text aligned in Bootstrap 4 Grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a grid using Bootstrap 4's Grid that I want to look like the following:

[image]

I have almost 100% of it complete, the issue I have is the alignment of the vertically rotated text overlaps the color grid. I am using Bootstrap Extensions `content rotate` to get the text rotated. I just can't seem to figure out how to get the labels aligned.

[image]

Here is a codeply fiddle:
https://www.codeply.com/go/Xd4pcADxml

Comment: `row` only detect the regular behavior of `col` and the extension rotates the text only. There is not a naive way to deal with responsive text even in this situation is rotated. so the easy suggest I can immediately come out based on the document is to change `rotate-sm-l-90` to `rotate-sm-r-90`. But again you still have to deal with the outer box size or you can manually set the height of row and reduce the size of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of "rotate-sm-l-90" class i added custom css for labels.

```
.vertical-label {
transform: rotate(-180deg);
writing-mode: vertical-lr;
padding: 16px;
```

}

[Here is the result](https://www.codeply.com/go/mR2W2IMBm0)